# Time Complexity questions

Tags: time-complexity

I'm studying for a test, and got stuck on Time Complexity questions. Hope you guys could show me how to solve these.
I searched everywhere I could but didn't find a way.

[image]

[image]

they are two different qustions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, could you please be more specific? I can't see anything like my questions there.

Comment: The first is covered immediately by the master theorem. For the second one, try writing out some of the terms and see where it gets you. For example, $T(n)=10T(n-1)-25T(n-2)+f(n) = 10(10T(n-2)-25T(n-3)+f(n-1))-25T(n-2)+f(n) = 75T(n-2)-250T(n-3)+...$

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks but I could not understand how you did it. This is my main problem. Is there a .pdf file that explains it? I learn by myself and does not have teacher.

Comment: The page I linked you to gives detailed instructions about how to solve recurrences with a number of techniques.